# Is it possible to call such properties "cocycle conditions"?

Tags: notation, terminology, homology-cohomology

Let $\mathcal O = \{\alpha,\beta,\ldots\}$ be a family of objects of general but similar type (numbers, functions,e.t.c.). Let $\{ X_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \mathcal O\}$ be a family of linear spaces (only for the sake of simplicity, in general it can be something other) and $\{ A_\alpha^\beta \mid \alpha,\beta \in \mathcal O \}$ be a family of linear operators such that $A_\alpha^\beta \in L(X_\alpha,X_\beta)$. They satisfy additional conditions: 
$$
    A_\alpha^\alpha = \mathrm{id_{X_\alpha}}, \; \alpha \in \mathcal O, \\
    A_\beta^\gamma A_\alpha^\beta = A_\alpha^\gamma, \; \alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathcal O, \\
    A_\gamma^\delta A_\beta^\gamma A_\alpha^\beta = A_\alpha^\delta, \; \alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta \in \mathcal O.
$$
Is it normal to say that family $\{A_\alpha^\beta \mid \alpha,\beta \in \mathcal O\}$ satysfies cocycle conditions? If it is ok, maybe there is some underlying cohomology theory?

Comment: The third condition is redundant; it follows from the second.